# Like masthead, motto, logo

Tags: meaning, word-choice, single-word-requests

What is the word for an image and/or phrase that might be painted or hung on the main wall of an organization's lobby? Not their "logo" but a deeper, more complex, more internal symbol. That's representative of the organization's identity to its members.
I'm thinking of the words "masthead" and "motto" as possible choices.

Comment: _Emblem?_ - a design or object that is a symbol of something such as a country or organization [[MacMillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/emblem#emblem_4)]

Comment: @ermanen I think emblem would be the right choice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In book publishing, many companies have an image associated with their books and their publishing house—for example, the Penguin Books penguin, the Pocket Books kangaroo, the Modern Library torchbearer, the Knopf borzoi, the Simon & Schuster seed sower, the Viking longboat, the Pantheon temple, the Random House mansion, the Oxford university seal, the Merriam-Webster wreathed MW, the Doubleday anchor, the Houghton Mifflin dolphin, and the Dent dolphin-and-anchor. These images/logos/devices are called *colophons*.

*Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* offers the following relevant definition of *colophon*:

> **colophon** *n* **2 :** an identifying mark, emblem, or device used by a printer or a publisher

But as this definition suggests, the term *colophon* is primarily used within the publishing industry.

Another possible term is *insignia*. Again from the *Eleventh Collegiate*:

> **insignia** *n* **1 :** a badge of authority or honor **2 :** a distinguishing mark or sign

In U.S. periodical publishing, *masthead* refers to the list of employees who contributed to the writing, editing, design, and production of the publication in question, so that wouldn't be a good choice for what you're talking about.

Comment: Nice work on insignia.

Answer (score 0):

[Slogan](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/slogan)

- A motto associated with a political party or movement or other group.

Most slogans are recognised by users of certain products (assuming we're talking about companies).

> Think Different — Apple
>
> Just Do It — Nike
>
> i'm lovin' it — McDonald's

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily in the strict legal sense of the word (although most images and/or phrases of this kind are protected [trademarks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trademark)), but a company is often symbolized and known best by its "Signature Trademark."